# ASP.NET DropDownList server control does not fire jQuery .Change() when selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

I'm using jQuery mobile for our mobile website. The Asp.net dropdownlist control appears as a jQuery mobile select.

HTML:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server" >
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCom" class="ddlCom" name="ddlCom" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <table id="compTable"></table>

</asp:Content>
```

and Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#<%=ddlCom.ClientID %>').select(function () {
    alert("it works");
});

$('.ddlCom').change(function () {
    alert("css works");
});

$('select[name=ddlCom]').change(function () {
    alert("css works");
});

$("select[id$=ddlCom]").change(function() {
    alert(" works");
```

});

none of these will be triggered when I click and select a value form the dropdownlist. What gives?

Thanks,

EDIT:

Generated HTML:

```
<div class="ui-select">
<a href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c">
<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
<span class="ui-btn-text">Finance Department</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow">
</span></span></a>
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlCom" id="ctl00_MainContent_ddlCom" class="ddlCom" data-mini="true" tabindex="-1">
    <option value="1">......</option>
    <option value="2">.....</option>
    <option value="3">......</option>
</select></div>
```

Comment: can you provide the generated html for the drop down?

Comment: ASP.NET likes to hook into events. You could use something like `$('.ddlCom').off('change').on('change', function(){..});` to clear any existing binding, but your validators (lol) might stop working.

Comment: Please see the edit for the generated HTML

Comment: you're using `.ready()` which should **not** be used in jQM. if you're using _Multi page model_ and the page that contains select has an id, this should work for you `$(document).on("pageinit", "#pageID", function () { $("#selectID").on("change", function () { /* code */ }); });`

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#<%=ddlCom.ClientID %>').change(function () {
    alert("it works");
});
```

This will work if you change it to "Change" like I did.

also this

```
$('.ddlCom').change(function () {
    alert("css works");
});
```

if you change your declarion of the dropdown to specify the cssclass

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCom" CssClass="ddlCom" name="ddlCom" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

And this would have worked as well if you didn't have a typo in it

```
$("select[id$='ddlCom']").change(function() {
    alert(" works");
});
```

Comment: I tried all that, none works which is weird. Please see the edit for the generated HTML. I only changed to select() because change() did not work.

Comment: Then there is something else amiss. Check your console in firebug or chrome. You can see it working over here http://jsfiddle.net/4u2dA/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there are double references to jQuery and jQuery mobile in different versions in the Masterpage and the page header so it broke. It's working as it should now. Thanks all